# BI Publisher Ribbon not appearing in Office 365 64bit

Tags: bi-publisher

I've office 365 install in my system (64 bit) and my OS is windows 10 Enterprise(64 bit). I've downloaded bi publisher desktop from [this](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/bi-publisher/downloads.html) location and installed 64 bit version of it using Administrator access.

After installing I can't see any Ribbon 'Bi Publisher' in my Word application. Also, I can't see this add-in in File->Options->Add-in window. I checked all options (Active/Inactive/COM Add-in/Disable Items) but this addin is not there at all.

I searched many blogs where they are suggesting to run below file -

C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\TBAddInSetup64.msi

but when I'm trying to run this, it throws an error "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove program on the Control Panel'

Can anybody suggest me how to populate this ribbon in Office 365(64 bit)?

Comment: Which version are you trying? It will show up under "Add-Ins" ribbon section. I have BI Publisher 11.1.1.9 installed in Word 2001 (Build 12430.20264). It is not listed in my File/Options/Add-in section.

Comment: I'm trying with 'Oracle BI Publisher Desktop 12.2.1.4.0 for 64 bit Office on Windows' , it was showing earlier with older version but my office laptop has updated the word to office 365 64 bit so I downloaded and installed it.

Comment: Oracle is pretty bad with software instillation. Try rebooting, uninstall, reboot, install, reboot, and then see if it's in Word as expected. If that doesn't work, uninstall the 12.2.1.4, and then install 11.1.1.9. It's on the same download page as the one you linked.

Comment: I had the same issue, solved by running `C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\setup.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by unistalling (C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\TBAddInSetup.msi) in order to install (C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\TBAddInSetup64.msi).

I think that the another version without the "64" it's the 32 bits version and in my case, my windows and office are 64 bits so I think that I must have the 64 bits version of that programm.

After all of this, if you don't see the pluging, check it on Windows/Archive/Options/Complements/Manage(Complements COM)/Go

And you should see BIPublisher available for choose

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I have separate accounts for development work and administration. I installed with the admin login but the add-in would not run under my developer credentials.  Apparently Oracle expects you to only run Word under the same admin-enabled account that was used to install the software.  My Desktop Support department had to grant admin to my dev account, install and then drop the admin permissions.  So now it's installed and runs under Dev, but the Preview function throws a Java error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not an administrator on your pc, probably an admin user installed the Add-in. If so, with your user logged in, run: C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\TBAddUser.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).